# Convert list to dictionary with duplicate keys using dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7

Good day all,

I am trying to convert a list of length-2 items to a dictionary using the below:

```
my_list = ["b4", "c3", "c5"]
my_dict = {key: value for (key, value) in my_list}
```

The issue is that when a key occurrence is more than one in the list, only the last key and its value are kept.

So in this case instead of

```
my_dict = {'c': '3', 'c': '5', 'b': '4'}
```

I get

```
my_dict = {'c': '5', 'b': '4'}
```

How can I keep all key:value pairs even if there are duplicate keys.
Thanks

Comment: What would you expect to get back for `my_dict['c']`?

Comment: `for (key, value) in my_list` shouldn't be working

Comment: @MMF: why not?  Each element in `my_list` has two values when iterated over.

Comment: @Patrick Yeah, hadn't thought of that. Embarrassed.

Comment: @MMF sure it does.  strings are iterables and can be unpacked

Comment: oups sorry, you're right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For one key in a dictionary you can only store one value.

You can chose to have the value as a list.

```
{'b': ['4'], 'c': ['3', '5']}
```

following code will do that for you :

```
new_dict = {}
for (key, value) in my_list:
    if key in new_dict:
        new_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        new_dict[key] = [value]
print(new_dict)
# output: {'b': ['4'], 'c': ['3', '5']}
```

Same thing can be done with `setdefault`. Thanks @Aadit M Shah for pointing it out

```
new_dict = {}
for (key, value) in my_list:
    new_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(new_dict)
# output: {'b': ['4'], 'c': ['3', '5']}
```

Same thing can be done with `defaultdict`. Thanks @MMF for pointing it out.

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for (key, value) in my_list:
    new_dict[key].append(value)
print(new_dict)
# output: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': ['4'], 'c': ['3', '5']})
```

you can also chose to store the value as a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'b': '4'}, {'c': '3'}, {'c': '5'}]
```

following code will do that for you

```
new_list = [{key: value} for (key, value) in my_list]
```

Comment: with `defaultdict` you won't need to check if a key is in the dictionnary ;)

Comment: @MMF no disagreement there.

Comment: Even better, just do `new_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`.

Comment: @AaditMShah add your's and MMF's inputs in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the `O(n^2)` asymptotic behaviour you can use a dict comprehension including a list comprehension:

```
>>> {key: [i[1] for i in my_list if i[0] == key] for (key, value) in my_list}
{'b': ['4'], 'c': ['3', '5']}
```

or the [`iteration_utilities.groupedby`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/groupedby.html) function (which *might* be even faster than using `collections.defaultdict`):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import groupedby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> groupedby(my_list, key=itemgetter(0), keep=itemgetter(1))
{'b': ['4'], 'c': ['3', '5']}
```

Comment: There's `itertools.groupby`, but "_Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function._" That makes the function almost useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict` to avoid checking if a key is in the dictionnary or not :

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in my_list:
    my_dict[k].append(v)
```

Output :

```
defaultdict(list, {'b': ['4'], 'c': ['3', '5']})
```

Comment: Even better, just do `my_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)` using a regular dictionary.