# Splitting list into a dictionary of lists by a custom key function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I implemented a small helper function that splits a list into a dictionary by a custom key function.
The following implementation works, but feels rather un-pythonic:

```
def classify_list_by_key(l, key_func):
    result = defaultdict(list)

    for item in l:
        result[key_func(item)].append(item)

    return result
```

I tried using the following dict comprehension, which obviously has horrible performance with a lot of unnecessary calls to `key_func` and quadratic run-time.

```
def classify_list_by_key_dict_comprehension(l, key_func):
    return {key_func(x): [y for y in objects if key_func(x) == key_func(y)] for x in l}
```

---

Sample in- and output:

```
str_list = "these are some test strings for testing classify_list_by_key function".split()
print(classify_list_by_key(str_list, len))
```

produces

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {5: ['these'], 3: ['are', 'for'], 4: ['some', 'test'], 7: ['strings', 'testing'], 20: ['classify_list_by_key'], 8: ['function']})
```

---

Is there a better / more pythonic way to achieve this using built-ins or standard library modules?

Comment: I've been thinking of different options, but I don't find anything better. Also, the second option, not only does it have O(2) but looks less readable to me. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41165820/9415337) is the only thing which has come up, but at the end of the day you are just hiding and remapping the implementation they did. So I think that there is no more Pythonic way. You can also consider using a standard dict and the setdefault function.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, using `setdefault` might actually work well here! I also agree that the dict comprehension does nothing for readability.

Comment: "The following implementation works, but feels rather un-pythonic:" well, it isn't unpythonic. Why do you *think* it is unpythonic? Why would you not use it? You clearly understand your alternative performs worse?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using `groupby` from `itertools`, but it requires a sorted list for that purpose.

Here is the code for that:

```
from itertools import groupby
str_list = "these are some test strings for testing classify_list_by_key function".split()
str_list.sort(key=len)
res = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(str_list, key=len)}
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{3: ['are', 'for'], 4: ['some', 'test'], 5: ['these'], 7: ['strings', 'testing'], 8: ['function'], 20: ['classify_list_by_key']}
```

Comment: Notice the sort is not necessary per se.

Comment: @miquelvir Yeah, you are right, it works without sort too

Comment: @miquelvir Modified the code, no need of unnecessary sorting. Thanks for the notice!

Comment: The sort **is** necessary, so I rolled it back. To convince yourself, try the input strings `['one', 'four', 'two']`. The `one` won't make it into the result, because it will be in a separate group from the `two`, and the latter list will replace the former.

Comment: @CutePanda, if sorting is needed, I don't think this is any better than the original solution. You need to sort the array AND iterate through it after the groupby. The original solution seems better.

Comment: Comparison-based sorting is O(n lg n), and the built-in Python sort is quite well optimized. That said, practicality beats purity, and there's no need to make everything follow functional style.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an alternative implementation which does not force to use a defaultdict:

```
def classify_list_by_key(l, key_func):
    result = {}

    for item in l:
        result.setdefault(key_func(item), []).append(item)

    return result

str_list = "these are some test strings for testing classify_list_by_key function".split()
print(classify_list_by_key(str_list, len))
```

Comment: How is this better? It is certainly not more pythonic to re-invent the wheel

Comment: I agree that re-inventing the wheel is not more pythonic. As stated, the solution of itertools is the one which I would use. My point is that, if he needs to implement it himself (for some reason), this implementation can be slightly better than the suggested one.

Comment: Why would you use the itertools solutions?? It is *more inefficient* than the OP's solution.

Comment: Well you are right. The itertools solution is actually pretty bad. @Karl Knechtel just explained to us that the sort is necessary, which means that sorting and iterating; it should not be the accepted solution.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have fixed my answer.